# Win 10 installer on Macbook produces "couldn't create new partition" error

Tags: macos, partitioning, boot-camp

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on my late 2011 Macbook Pro. As it's not officially supported, I'm bypassing the use of boot camp assistant.

I have a 256GB SSD hosting OSX, I'd like to split that for Windows.

As I've read elsewhere, I created a FAT32 partition with diskutil command, set boot flags (as described [here](http://tinyurl.com/jrt9e2y)), and fixed up GPT boot records (as described [here](http://tinyurl.com/l5q4tkt)).

When I boot up on a Win10 installer usb drive, I select the partition, hit "format" to convert it to NTFS, and I get the error below. What can be done? Seemingly the installer creates its additional partitions, so I don't know why the error happens.

Comment: Could you edit your question and include the error.

Comment: Post the output from the Terminal commands `sudo  fdisk  /dev/disk0` and `sudo  gpt  -r  show  /dev/disk0`. Neither command will change your computer. Enter your login password it asked. I want to check if your disk is partitioned correctly. How did you create the Win10 installer?

Comment: After extensive research, I see that installing Windows on a Macbook directly is really complex and tricky. Cloning a pre-made partition from a virtual machine is easier and works universally [link](http://huguesval.com/blog/2012/02/installing-windows-7-on-a-mac-without-superdrive-with-virtualbox/). This does not answer the problem above, and is not a direct alternative, but for most, it's better.

Comment: @poisonborz - You should supply the error if you want an answer to your question.  What you seek to do, actually is incredibly easy to do, once you understand what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I had that problem and I solved it by making some space between partitions. In my case I didn't fill the Windows partition, but left about 500Mb at the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Basic steps to install 64 bit Windows 10 are as follows. I assume here that your current configuration is the default "Out of the Box" OS X installation.

1. Download the correct Boot Camp Support Software for your Mac.
   Transfer these files to a FAT formatted flash drive. For your Mac,
   use the same software as for a 64 bit Windows 7 installation. These
   files can be found at [Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5621](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720?locale=en_US)
2. Use the Disk Utility to reduce the size of your OS X partition. In
   the empty space, create a FAT formatted partition with the label
   BOOTCAMP.
3. Burn the Windows 10 iso file to a DVD. You can use the Disk Utility
   to do this. I always use a RW DVD. This takes longer to burn, but is
   reusable.
4. Restart the Mac with the DVD in the optical drive. Hold down the
   alt/option key and select the DVD icon with the label Windows.
5. Install Windows to the Boot Camp partition. You will have to tell
   the installer to reformat this partition as NTFS. DO NOT CHANGE THE
   PARTITIONING DURING THE INSTALLATION PROCESS.
6. At some point during the installation, the computer will reboot.
   When it does, it will boot to OS X. This is to be expected. Go to
   System Preferences and instruct OS X to boot back to Windows. The
   installation process will continue.
7. After the Windows installation has completed, install the Boot Camp
   Support software stored on the flash drive. To accomplish this, you
   will have to right click on the icon and select Compatibility Mode.

I do not consider the process to be that difficult. The most challenging step is creating the FAT formatted partition labeled BOOTCAMP. If something goes wrong, you are in danger of loosing data on your OS X partition.